# How to rename dataframe with file name in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, naming

I have several csv files in a folder that I need to read and do the same thing to each file. I want to rename each dataframe that is created with the file name, but am not sure how. Could I store the file names in a list and then refer to them later somehow...? My current code is bellow. Thank you in advance.

```
import os
Path = "C:\Users\DATA"
filelist = os.listdir(Path)
for x in filelist:
    RawData = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\DATA\%s" % x)
```

Comment: Use a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Arrays (do you really mean `list`?) are indexed with `int`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you have just one dataframe with all files?

```
import os
path = "C:\Users\DATA"
raw_data = {i: pd.read_csv(os.path.abspath(i)) for i in os.listdir(path)}
```